# move an image inside a picturebox

Tags: c#

I used the following code to move the image inside the image box, but it may come out of the frame when crawling with the mouse right or left. I want the image not to leave the frame of the image.

my code The image is moving but is outside the frame designated for the image.

```
   private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
          
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    if ((e.Button == 0))
                    {
                        

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        pictureBox1.Left = (pictureBox1.Left
                              + (e.X - mousePosX));
                        pictureBox1.Top = (pictureBox1.Top
                                    + (e.Y - mousePosY));
                 
                }

                //}


            }
        }
```

What I want is to move the image. And the picture does not come out of the picture box and it keeps moving inside the picture box frame and does not come out of it as shown in the picture..

[image]

Comment: _"it may come out of the frame"_ -- out of what frame? The code you posted is moving the `PictureBox` control itself. Would you prefer to keep that control in one place and move the image within it? If you want to move the control, you need to provide more details about what contains that control. Please provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Unless you draw an image onto the PBox you can't move an image within it. You can, however, move a PBox within, say, a Panel if you have nested it in it..

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you can try to do something like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
    {
        if ((e.Button == 0))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what you meant, but if you want to change the position of the image inside your picture box, that's the way to look. In your original code, you were changing the position of the picture box itself, not the image.

Comment: see the picture